# line / margin / border inside of the div with div styling (html / css)

Tags: css, html, line, styling

For some practical reasons, I need to achieve the center / middle line inside of the div with div styling.

```
<div style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 80px; height: 90px; border-left: solid 1px black;" onclick="this.style.background='rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)';" oncontextmenu="return false;"></div>
```

div in action ->  http://jsfiddle.net/ZkC68/

How to achieve this?
If there isn't a better way, I was thinking to move for ex. left border inside, but I don't know how...

Comment: could you please clarify? Do you want to position child elements to center/middle?

Comment: I basically just want to style the empty div - I want to style the center line in the same way as I can style borders and bg color (style="[here];"). I don't want to insert any new element.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to style the center line directly I think that's not possible. (no such css selector exists) However, you can do something like this:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="center-line">Center line</div>
</div>
```

And the CSS for styling as requested:

```
#center-line
{
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
padding: 20px; //not necessary, but makes it look good imo
}
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/cdkyZ/1/